# HTTP Post connection android to send text and image?

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to create a HTTP POST connection to send data and image to the server. But the problem is my URL has 3 query parameters.
Example: "www.url.aspx?uname=xxx&pass=xxxx&style=xxxx"

This is the code I have tried till far

```
public String httppost(Bitmap cameraBitmap, String url, String data) {
      /* Create the channel for communicaton */
      InputStream is = null;
      /* Send request to server */

      try {
        /* Create the POST */
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);



        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = null;
        cameraBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        b = stream.toByteArray();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> arguments =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
        arguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", Base64.encode(b, 0, b.length)));
        /* Add the login information "POST" variables in the php */
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arguments));

        /* Execute the http POST and get the response */
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        return null;
      }

      /* Read response from server */
      try {
        /* Read the response stream */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        /* Copy the response to StringBuilder */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        /* Return the response as string */
        return sb.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        return null;
      }
    }
```

But it does not work.

How can I add query string to the URL?

Comment: Can't you just concatenate your params in the url in a Get fashion? Something like: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url + "?" + param1Key + "=" + param1value);

Comment: If you want to attach query string to the URL you must use HTTP Get, i think that the problem here is another, try to inspect your logcat or check the server response, probably there are problem during the post request/response

Comment: @jDur It dosnt work like that if you need to post your data

Comment: @phemt.latd I need to post my data.